# DOCX table to xml using XSL

Tags: xml, xslt, docx

I have a docx file with a working-schedule table like so:

```
        monday | tuesday | wednesday | thursday | friday | saturday | sunday
Peter     5    |   4     |           |    6     |   5    |          |   11
John      2    |         |    1      |    6     |   5    |     4    |
etc..
```

I extracted the document.xml from the docx and am trying to create the following xml using this xml.

```
<schedule>
   <monday>
     <shift name="Peter" time="5" />
     <shift name="John"  time="2" />
   </monday>
   <tuesday>
 etc...
```

The only thing that I don't know how to do yet is add the shifts to the appropriate day. The xml I managed to get is:

```
<schedule>
   <monday>
     <shift name="Peter" time="5" />
   </monday>
   <monday>
     <shift name="John"  time="2" />
   </monday>
   <tuesday>
etc..
```

How do i fix this?

Attachements:
the document.xml (extracted from the docx) [HERE](http://happylinks.nl/rooster/rooster.xml)
the xsl I created [HERE](http://happylinks.nl/rooster/rooster.xsl)

Comment: Is that the right document xml you have provided? It looks more like your current output XML, as opposed to the input XML document.

Comment: I updated the xml, the xsl was already applied to that. Now the original is online.

Comment: You haven't provided the source XML!. Please, edit the question and provide it.

Comment: I linked the source XML at the bottom of my question. Here is the link again: [link](http://happylinks.nl/rooster/rooster.xml)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Apply to your current result this transformation (Muenchian grouping)**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
 <xsl:key name="kDayByName" match="/*/*" use="name()"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="/*/*"/>

 <xsl:template match=
  "/*/*[generate-id()
       =
        generate-id(key('kDayByName', name())[1])
       ]
  ">

  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select=
        "key('kDayByName', name())/node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on this XML document**:

```
<schedule>
    <monday>
        <shift name="Peter" time="5" />
    </monday>
    <monday>
        <shift name="John"  time="2" />
    </monday>
</schedule>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<schedule>
    <monday>
        <shift name="Peter" time="5" />
        <shift name="John" time="2" />
    </monday>
</schedule>
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! One little question: how do i apply multiple XSL stylesheets without saving the result of the first. I am working in PHP. Thank you very much!

Comment: @user189172: there are several question about "multi-pass transformation" Typically: `<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vrtfPass1">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="/*"/>
 </xsl:variable>
 
 <xsl:variable name="vPass1" select="ext:node-set($vrtfPass1)"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="$vPass1" mode="pass2"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>`

Comment: Thank you for your help, I have been struggeling with your Multi-pass code but haven't got it to work yet. I don't know where I should place the XSl's in that code. I have been googling a lot but the examples are very complicated. Could you help me once again?